# Sudo command is not getting exited

Tags: 16.04, sudo

The commands with root privilege are not getting an exit.

For example `sudo cp abc.txt def.txt`. It will ask for the password. Once I enter the password the terminal will stand still. It will require me to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit. Some of the commands are working fine but commands like `cp` is doing a corrupted copy.

Why is this happening? How to solve this issue?

Comment: I'd assume the `cp` never completes.   The command won't return until the command (`cp`) completes as you tell it to run in the background. Are the source & destinations real files, or devices that never reach eof() ?

Comment: `cp` I gave as an example. Whichever commands I use with `sudo` prefix is behaving like this. Eg: `sudo rm -r FolderName` also will act like this. But when I press `ctrl+c` the command will exit & the folder is getting deleted which means working fine.

Comment: the `cp` command actually worked. How big is your file ?

Comment: Does `sudo whoami` work? Also, what's the output of `uptime` right after you press `Ctl` + `c` when a command doesn't exit? Lastly, how many cores do you have?

Comment: I would check your 'root' users .bash_profile, .profile, .login... files for a structure/command-set which waits for input, loops or does something that never exits...  Then check your *logout scripts.

Comment: @JohnJoe Today I tried with a `pem` file. And I was unable to connect to the server using the copied one.